# Regression across multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I'm new to coding and am having a hard time regressing multiple columns on one column.

The dataframe consists of ~200 securities. I want to regress each security on a specific column (stock1 regressed on stock4, stock2 regressed on stock4, stock3 regressed on stock4, etc.)

Then, I want a new dataframe of the regression coefficients and the securities.

```
regr = LinearRegression()
y_regression = np.array(df.y).reshape(-1,1)
beta = lambda x: list(regr.fit(np.array(x).reshape(-1,1), y_regression).coef_)
beta = df.apply(beta)
```

The code will correctly perform the calculations across all columns, but it comes out as an np.ndarray and looks like this [[1.25678]]. The only way I can get the code to work on multiple columns is if I create a list of the arrays. My new dataframe has this format:

Stock1    [[1.25678]]
Stock2    [[0.96782]]
etc.

How can I change the type so that it only gives me the inner number (1.25678,etc)?

Comment: Try removing the list() from your lambda function. i.e. `beta = lambda x: regr.fit(np.array(x).reshape(-1,1), y_regression).coef_`

Comment: if I do that I get ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regr = LinearRegression()
y_regression = np.array(df.y).reshape(-1,1)
beta = lambda x: list(regr.fit(np.array(x).reshape(-1,1), y_regression).coef_)[0]
beta = df.apply(beta)
```

Comment: No, it returns the same error: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: File "C:\Users\Ben\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 355, in extract_index
    raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index